# Using Facebook graph to get the fans of a fan page?

Tags: json, facebook

I have a fan page located at http://www.facebook.com/shop4tronix. I can access info on this page by going to:

```
http://graph.facebook.com/shop4tronix
```

However, I want a list of all the fans of my page returned. I figured something like this would work:

```
http://graph.facebook.com/shop4tronix/fans
```

But it doesn't. Is there any way to get a list of fans returned using this method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like it's not possible. If you google a bit, you'll find people scraping the fan pages (as there seem to be no API access).

Comment: Also by scrapping the Fanpaage plugin you only get a certain number of Fans - and after a while only the same Fans over and over again - I was able to get less than 10000 from a 1 Mio Fanpage!