# How to get facebook page users who likes the fan page using facebook graph api

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-page

the fan page 335667609918222 count is 2 but when i tried to access the below url https://graph.facebook.com/335667609918222/likes?access_token=CAAG4yxdE1UsBAFu8L0ZCdlFWWeJy2hCOnYtr9ZB42LvbqlqsPs1PAwHfZB3RIMVGXFcmwDMR6xVTvCjU1Pp3ler6FG17SGzY6lW5frZBaaJaUsfksHNnC3jvl9sjNgaTXi22C9VQsw95VdRWHluLdfy5fai0ij0yBNMmp64dObycqumuCBeO3O0JQj8q8STBRS9JZA2wTVQZDZD  I am always getting the empty data.
Please help me out

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using Facebook graph to get the fans of a fan page?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2743937/using-facebook-graph-to-get-the-fans-of-a-fan-page)

Answer (score 0):

The Facebook Graph API doesn't support that.

You can only query: "Does this user like Facebook Page X?", not "Give me a list of all users that Like Facebook Page X".

Also, your access_token is in the URL, you should probably keep that private.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply. So this means that we cannot get the users who liked my fan page using graph api?? Is this correct

Comment: That's correct, the Facebook Graph API doesn't support that query. I think it is mainly for privacy reasons.

Comment: Thank you so much for the prompt reply